# Can't get gnuplot to fill below line

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to get gnuplot 5.0 under OS X 10.10.3 to fill blue below the lower series in this plot. I've tried lots of variations for the line `dataFileForecast using 1:4 with filledcurves above y1=0 linestyle 3`, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Here's the source:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/gnuplot
reset

set terminal pngcairo enhanced background "#000000" font "Lato-Light,20" linewidth 1 rounded size 2048,670
set output "10DayForecast.png"
dataFileForecast = "10DayForecast.csv"
set datafile separator ','
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
stats dataFileForecast using 2:4 nooutput

freezeWarning = 32.
Yhigh = STATS_max_x + 10.
Ylow = STATS_min_y - 10.

unset key
set border linetype rgb "#666666"
set boxwidth 0.25 relative
set style fill transparent solid 0.4
set style line 1 linetype rgb "#0066CC" # freeze line
set style line 2 linetype rgb "#FFFFFF" pointtype 7 pointsize .5 # points for both high and low temp
set style line 3 linetype rgb "#000077" # fill for low temp
set style line 4 linetype rgb "#FFFF00" # rain forecast
set style line 5 linetype rgb "#770000" # fill for high temp
set style line 6 linetype rgb "#FF7777" # line for high temp
set style line 7 linetype rgb "#3377FF" # line for low temp

set label "°" right

unset mxtics
set tics textcolor rgb "#666666"

# X Axis
set xdata time 
set xtics format "%a" nomirror
set autoscale xfix
set offsets 12*60*60,12*60*60,0,0

# Y Axis
set yrange [Ylow:Yhigh]
unset ytics
if (32 > Ylow) set ytics 32,1,32 tc rgb "#FFFFFF" font ",18"
set ytics format "%2.0f°" nomirror

# Y2 Axis
set y2tics format "%2.0f%%" textcolor "#FFFF00" nomirror
set y2range [0:100]

plot dataFileForecast using 1:6 with impulses linestyle 4 axes x1y2,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:2:4 with filledcurves above linestyle 5,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:2 with lines linestyle 6,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:2 with points linestyle 2,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:2:3 with labels offset 1.75,0.5 textcolor "#FFFFFF" font ",18",\
    dataFileForecast using 1:4 with filledcurves above y1=0 linestyle 3,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:4 with lines linestyle 7,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:4 with points linestyle 2,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:4:5 with labels offset 1.75,0.5 textcolor "#FFFFFF" font ",18",\
    freezeWarning with filledcurve above y1=0 linestyle 1
```

And here's a data file:

```
2015-06-29,94,94°,69,69°,20.0
2015-06-30,99,99°,72,72°,0.0
2015-07-01,102,102°,73,73°,0.0
2015-07-02,96,96°,69,69°,0.0
2015-07-03,94,94°,68,68°,10.0
2015-07-04,92,92°,67,67°,0.0
2015-07-05,91,91°,63,63°,0.0
2015-07-06,91,91°,62,62°,0.0
2015-07-07,91,91°,61,61°,0.0
2015-07-08,91,91°,63,63°,0.0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, why this doesn't work. Could be a bug. As workaround you can give a third column in the `using` statement to indicate the lower boundary of the filled area:

```
plot ...,\
    dataFileForecast using 1:4:(0) with filledcurves linestyle 3
```

This gives the output

[image]

The `freezeWarning` area is plotted correctly, if the yrange includes this region.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this might be a bug in 5.0. I see there's a 5.0.1. Once that's available in MacPorts, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Seems indeed, that this should be fixed in 5.0.1. The [release notes](http://gnuplot.info/ReleaseNotes_5_0_1.html) contain a line `FIX breakage in plot style filledcurves {above|below} y1=<yval>`. I cannot test it at the moment, but that looks good.